# How to change Checkbox style and Background Color in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, checkbox, xamarin.forms, styles

I am new at Xamarin forms and renderers, Can you please help me out in this,
Thank you in advance.

I have created a checkbox but I want to change its background color like in picture.
[image: Expected UI for Checkbox]

Now you can see in image default checkbox is there I want to change its background and style how can I do that?

```
<local:Checkbox x:Name="chkBrand" AutomationId="AutoIdCheckBox"
                Content="{Binding LblBrand}"
                Checked="{Binding Chk,Mode=TwoWay}">
</local:Checkbox>
```

Checkbox.cs

```
public class Checkbox : Xamarin.Forms.View
{

    public static readonly BindableProperty CheckedProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create("Checked",
            typeof(bool),
            typeof(Checkbox),
            false, BindingMode.TwoWay, propertyChanged: OnCheckedPropertyChanged);

    public static readonly BindableProperty ContentProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create("Content",
            typeof(string),
            typeof(Checkbox),
            "Content", BindingMode.OneWay);

    public static readonly BindableProperty FontSizeProperty =
      BindableProperty.Create("FontSize",
          typeof(double),
          typeof(Checkbox),
          default(double), BindingMode.OneWay);


    public bool Checked
    {
        get
        {
            return (bool)GetValue(CheckedProperty);
        }

        set
        {
            if (this.Checked != value)
            {
                SetValue(CheckedProperty, value);
                if (CheckedChanged != null)
                    CheckedChanged.Invoke(this, new CheckedChangedEventArgs(value));
            }
        }
    }

    public string Content
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)GetValue(ContentProperty);
        }

        set
        {
            SetValue(ContentProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public double FontSize
    {
        get
        {
            return (double)GetValue(FontSizeProperty);
        }

        set
        {
            SetValue(FontSizeProperty, value);
        }
    }


    public event EventHandler<CheckedChangedEventArgs> CheckedChanged;


    private static void OnCheckedPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldvalue, object newvalue)
    {
        var checkBox = (Checkbox)bindable;
        checkBox.Checked = newvalue != null ? (bool)newvalue : false;
    }
}
```

and platform wise renderer are used. Adding UWP renderer for reference

```
public class CheckboxRenderer : ViewRenderer<Checkbox, CheckBox>
{
    public new static void Init()
    {
        var temp = DateTime.Now;
    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Checkbox> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Element == null)
            return;

        if (Control == null)
        {
            var checkBox = new CheckBox();
            checkBox.Checked += CheckBox_Checked;
            checkBox.Unchecked += CheckBox_Unchecked;

            SetNativeControl(checkBox);
        }

        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            Control.Content = e.NewElement.Content;
            Control.IsChecked = e.NewElement.Checked;
            Control.IsEnabled = e.NewElement.IsEnabled;
            if (default(double) != e.NewElement.FontSize)
                Control.FontSize = e.NewElement.FontSize;
        }

    }

    private void CheckBox_Unchecked(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Element.Checked = Control.IsChecked.GetValueOrDefault();
    }

    private void CheckBox_Checked(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Element.Checked = Control.IsChecked.GetValueOrDefault();

    }

    private void CheckBox_Content(object sender)
    {
        Element.Checked = Control.IsChecked.GetValueOrDefault();
    }


    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
        switch (e.PropertyName)
        {
            //case "IsVisible":
            //    Control.Hidden = Element.IsVisible;
            //    break;
            case "IsEnabled":
                Control.IsEnabled = Element.IsEnabled;
                break;
            case "Checked":
                Control.IsChecked = Element.Checked;
                break;
            case "Content":
                Control.Content = Element.Content;
                break;

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this,

1. Use nuget package to show check box **or**
2. A simple way to change the style is to use the image control for checkbox.
   Take two images as per your colour, one checked and other one is unchecked and do hide & show on click.